# properly assign records into correct parent using foreach php

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I have a similar arrays like below:

```
       $agents = [
          (object)["id"=> 301,"name"=> "Agent 1"],
           (object)["id"=> 303,"name"=> "Agent 2"],
           (object)["id"=> 301,"name"=> "Agent 3"],
           (object)["id"=> 305,"name"=> "Agent 4"],
           (object)["id"=> 306,"name"=> "Agent 5"],
           (object)["id"=> 303,"name"=> "Agent 6"]
        ];


         $locations =  [
             (object)["xid"=> 148,"location_name"=> "USA"],
             (object)["xid"=> 149,"location_name"=> "CHINA"],
             (object)["xid"=> 153,"location_name"=> "GERMANY"],
             (object)["xid"=> 156,"location_name"=> "CANADA"],
             (object)["xid"=> 167,"location_name"=> "SINGAPORE"],
             (object)["xid"=> 0,"location_name"=> "No Location"]
        ];

       
        $records = [
           (object)["agent_id"=> 301,"location_id"=> 156,"total"=> 10000],
           (object)["agent_id"=> 303,"location_id"=> 149,"total"=> 13000],
           (object)["agent_id"=> 301,"location_id"=> 156,"total"=> 10000],
           (object)["agent_id"=> 305,"location_id"=> 0,"total"=> 10000],
           (object)["agent_id"=> 306,"location_id"=> 148,"total"=> 10000],
           (object)["agent_id"=> 303,"location_id"=> 0,"total"=> 10000]
        ];
```

I am trying to assign the correct transactions into  $agent->locations->transactions but my loop is not working..

```
        foreach ($agents as $a) {
            foreach ($locations as $l) {
                $a->locations[]=$l;
                foreach ($records as $r) {
                    if($r->location_id == $l->xid && $r->agent_id == $a->id){
                        $l->transactions[] = $r;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

this is the result

[image]

what im trying to achieve is that, the transactions should be assigned/filtered under correct agent.. please help.. been looking on that loop for too long and have no idea how to achieve what i need :( ..

[image]

Comment: It would be best to convert the arrays to associative arrays. Then you wouldn't need all those nested loops, you could just index them.

Comment: Hi @Barmar tnx for stopping by, could you please elaborate further on how would I properly convert them please?

Comment: `foreach ($agents as $a) { $agents_assoc[$a->id] = $a; }`

Comment: You're doing `$a->locations[]=$l;` even when there's no relationship between the agent and the location. So every agent will be linked with every location. Is that really wanted?

Comment: Im fine with that.. all agent contains all locations.. but under location there should be transactions and thats where the correct/filtered transactions should be placed with correct parent ( agent ) and location id  thats why i had this condition 
`if($r->location_id == $l->xid && $r->agent_id == $a->id){ $l->transactions[] = $r;}` but its not working

Comment: But since every agent contains all locations, when you modify the transaction list for a location, that will be seen under all the agents, not just the agent with the same agent_id. You're not cloning the location objects, they're all references to the same object.

Comment: In PHP, objects are passed by reference, arrays are copied (unless you use `&` to make a reference variable).

Comment: I see.. I think this is where I really am confused coz I believe the variable values are retained on each loop ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are dealing with objects.** So, any modification made to it will reflect later on.

You did `$l->transactions[] = $r;`. So now that `$l` object will have previous transaction details too.

To solve this, you can create a quick clone of the object and modify this new object using [`clone`](https://www.php.net/language.oop5.cloning).

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

foreach($agents as $agent){
    $agent->locations = [];
    foreach($locations as $location){
        $location = clone $location;
        $location->transactions = [];
        foreach($records as $r){
            if($r->agent_id == $agent->id && $location->xid == $r->location_id){
                $location->transactions[] = $r;
            }
        }
        
        $agent->locations[] = $location;
    }
}
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/gNXhg)

Answer (score 1):

You should:

1. Create a location property for each agent.
2. While going through the records, figure out which agent and location the transaction belongs to. Then, place the transaction in the right location under the correct agent.

---

```
$agentIndex = [];
$locationIndex = [];

// moving to the index to quick lookup.
foreach ($agents as $agent) {
    $agent->locations = [];
    $agentIndex[$agent->id] = $agent;
}

foreach ($locations as $location) {
    $location->transactions = [];
    $locationIndex[$location->xid] = $location;
}


foreach ($records as $record) {
    $agent = $agentIndex[$record->agent_id] ?? null;
    $location = $locationIndex[$record->location_id] ?? null;

    if ($agent && $location) {
        // Add location to the agent does not exist
        if (!isset($agent->locations[$location->xid])) {
            $agent->locations[$location->xid] = $location;
        }
        $agent->locations[$location->xid]->transactions[] = $record;
    }
}

// mapping again with an indexed array
foreach ($agents as $agent) {
    $agent->locations = array_values($agent->locations);
}

print_r($agents);
```

---

> Moved the location inside the foreach.

```
$agentIndex = [];
$locationIndex = [];

foreach ($agents as $agent) {
    $agent->locations = [];
    $agentIndex[$agent->id] = $agent;
}

foreach ($locations as $location) {
    $locationIndex[$location->xid] = $location;
}

foreach ($records as $record) {
    $agent = $agentIndex[$record->agent_id] ?? null;
    
    if (isset($locationIndex[$record->location_id])) {
        $location = clone $locationIndex[$record->location_id];
    } else {
        $location = null;
    }

    if ($agent && $location) {
        if (!isset($agent->locations[$location->xid])) {
            $location->transactions = [];  
            $agent->locations[$location->xid] = $location;
        }
        $agent->locations[$location->xid]->transactions[] = $record;
    }
}


foreach ($agents as $agent) {
    $agent->locations = array_values($agent->locations);
}

print_r($agents);
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @Abdulla Nilam for the code.. yeah your explanation is what I actually needed to do.. but I just didnt had idea on how to achieve it .. now I tried your code and trying to understand how you did, its almost perfect but I saw a record that doesnt belong to the correct agent  .. https://pasteboard.co/WYrsc7S5dx4W.png

Comment: Sorry to be bothersome, havent used `clone` method since .. now im getting `__clone method called on non-object`

Comment: I really appreciate the time and help  Sir @Abdulla Nilam  .. I almost got it working.. the only one lacking on my code was actually that `clone` thing.. anyway I tried your code but i got the error and mr @nice_dev's answer was short and did not really changed my code..